# When using XmlSerializer.Serialize is it possible to discard elements that throw errors during serialization?

Tags: .net, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am looking to xml serialize data and I'm willing to accept losing some of that data since I expect noise to exist. This is a special utility designed to help throw stuff at walls better, not expected to be reliable but I want to get what I can out of it.

Ideally when I run `XmlSerializer.Serialize()` and an error occurs for a single element the element would just get replaced with an error object or default object. If the element was just completely skipped that would also be fine.

- I'd prefer not to break the data into chunks and just hope that important data would survive.
- It is not a deal breaker if the output can't be deserialized later.
- I have set `XmlWriterSettings.CheckCharacters=false`

Comment: `XmlReader` will throw on **malformed** XML, no way around that.  As for invalid but well-formed XML (where the XML can't be deserialized to the specified type, e.g. an invalid integer value) I also don't think there is anything like that.  [How can I skip objects in XML Deserialization that throw errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64929205/3744182) and [Deserializing xml that contains an invalid data type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12820776/3744182) were never affirmatively answered.

Comment: You might try [transcoding to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJson.htm) and then deserializing, Json.NET supports [serialization error handling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm).  If your data model contains collections you will need to do something finicky to ensure that single-entry collections are properly transcoded as JSON arrays.

Comment: @dbc I am only looking for information on serializing. Not concerned about deserializing. Newtonsoft's serializing functions looks like they might be a route but ideally I wouldn't use 3rd party software.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, the usual question is about dealing handling deserialization errors.  But serialization is usually much more predictable than deserialization, why are exceptions getting thrown?  Does your data model have serializable properties that throw exceptions sometimes? If so I don't think `XmlSerializer` provides handlers or other extension points to swallow exceptions thrown by property getters.